# umount.crypt a volume ending in segmentation fault

Tags: ubuntu-20.04

I have a LUKS encrypted volume mounted at `/media/user/MY DRIVE`. It was mounted by `mount.crypt`.

A few hours later, I was done using it, so I executed `umount.crypt /media/user/MY DRIVE`.
As a result, it got a segmentation fault and core dumped.

```
apr 14 11:34:27 my-pc kernel: umount.crypt[153374]: segfault at 0 ip 000055871107223d sp 00007ffc44548da0 error 4 in mount.crypt[55871106e000+5000]
apr 14 11:34:27 my-pc kernel: Code: 48 8b 7d 00 e8 74 c6 ff ff 48 8b 7c 24 68 e8 fa c4 ff ff 48 89 45 00 4d 85 e4 74 21 49 8b 3c 24 e8 58 c6 ff ff 48 8b 7c 24 70 <80> 3f 2d 74 36 e8 d9 c4 ff ff 49 89 04 24 0f 1f 44 00 00 49 8b 3e
```

I also tried `umount.crypt_LUKS /media/user/MY DRIVE` but it also got "segmentation fault"

```
apr 14 11:35:04 my-pc kernel: umount.crypt_LU[153511]: segfault at 0 ip 00005648cc7f523d sp 00007ffe56620ae0 error 4 in mount.crypt[5648cc7f1000+5000]
apr 14 11:35:04 my-pc kernel: Code: 48 8b 7d 00 e8 74 c6 ff ff 48 8b 7c 24 68 e8 fa c4 ff ff 48 89 45 00 4d 85 e4 74 21 49 8b 3c 24 e8 58 c6 ff ff 48 8b 7c 24 70 <80> 3f 2d 74 36 e8 d9 c4 ff ff 49 89 04 24 0f 1f 44 00 00 49 8b 3e
```

Given the segfault happens in the same place, they are calling each other.

This issue doesn't happen all the time. It only happens if I leave the drive attached for many hours.

I have to detach it now so I will reboot the PC. However, I really would rather have a solution for some other time

This is an ubuntu 20.04 machine.
I have util-linux `2.34-0`.

Comment: Try using the -v option to mount.crypt to get more info (hopefully).  Try playing with -r or -n for umount.crypt.. also look in the system log.  My first guess would be that something didn't get installed correctly or somehow got corrupted.  Because "error 3" only applies to user mode applications, it is possible that it is the umount.crypt elf itself but difficult to tell from behind ***my*** screen and you probably don't know how to use `gdb` to find out the source of the fault.. :(  I hope you fix this.

Comment: `-v` didn't help. No more output exists. `-r` is not implemented (according to the manual). I'll try `-n` next time. The system log shows as I reproduced above. Nothing more appears. I can try to learn to use `gdb` for the purpose. I may get something. The most complex I used had been valgrind, though. I'll try valgrind next time it may help

Comment: Hee-hee.. imho, valgrind is harder to use than gdb. :) You *can* use gdb directly against your existing binaries but that will be a pain unless x64 asm is easy for you to read.  You will want to pull the source for umount.crypt, do a debug build, and run that copy under gdb so you can see the source of the barf.